# Are both of Vader's wrists artificial?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Are both of Vader's wrists artificial?

Vader's right hand is prosthetic (first cut off by Count Dooku in Episode II, and then we see the prosthetic fully exposed when Luke cuts the mechanical wrist off in Episode VI).

[image]

**What about his left wrist? Was it organic or artificial?**

I can't find anything on Google ("vader's left hand" or "vader's left wrist" only seem to show fan fiction).

Comment: related/helpful - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8555/3804

Comment: @Pureferret - actually that Q is **NOT** helpful at all after re-reading my answer! My supposedly comprehensive answer managed to miss the left hand loss by Anakin!!! :) :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**TL;DR**: His entire left hand was cut off by Obi-Wan Kenobi to the shoulder after they dueled on Mustafar in the lava, therefore **yes, both his wrists are artificial**.

---

From screenplay: http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html

```
ANAKIN: You underestimate my power!
OBI-WAN: Don't try it.
ANAKIN follows, and OBI-WAN cuts his young apprentice at the knees, 
       then cuts off his left arm in the blink of an eye. 
ANAKIN tumbles down the embankment and rolls to a stop near the edge of the lava.
```

And here's a screengrab from [Youtube clip of Mustafar batte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQXa70R8uZk&feature=related):

[image]

... and here's a clearer one (It's a lot more obvious that it's a stump in the video than a single frame though):

[image]

---

And, in conclusion:

> VANITY FAIR: What is the meaning of all the hands, arms, legs and heads being chopped off in the films that have emerged from Lucas' brain?
>   GEORGE LUCAS: **That's what happens when you play with swords**

Comment: New Trilogy goof, or deliberate?

Comment: @Pureferret - goof?

Comment: DVK, it means Mistake

Answer (score 36):

Obi-Wan cut off Anakin's left arm along with his legs in the lightsaber duel on Mustafar in *Revenge of the Sith*.  In the image below of Anakin in a hospital after the duel you can see the stump of his left arm before the prosthetic was attached.  Waving near the droid's head you can see Anakin's other mechanical arm and fingers.

[image: Anakin writhes in agony]